# Проблема в коде c++. Несовместимые типы операндов

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russiаn");
    const int max = { 100 };
    char array[max];
    cout << "Введите слово: ";
    cin.getline(array, max);
    int count{ 0 };
    while (array[count] != "\0") { // я не понимаю как исправить эту строчку кода и почему она не работает
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `array[count] != '\0'` или `array[count] != 0` или даже `array[count]`: `while (array[count]) count++;` Вы же пытались сравнивать *символ* со *строкой*

Comment: Странно, но array[count] != '\0'  - сработало, хотя от моей строчки кода отличается только кавычками, почему так?

Comment: Вы читали, что я написал? Что вы пытались сравнивать символ со строкой!

Answer (score 0):

`"\0"` - это строка ,а это символ `'\0'`. Правильно будет `(array[count] != '\0')` , так вы будете сравнивать символ с символом , а не строку с символом